Do there exist any analytical bounds on the Hurwitz Zeta function?
For the general real-valued Hurwitz Zeta Function
$$
\zeta\left(s,a\right),\quad s > 1,\ a > 0.
$$
Do there exist upper and/or lower bounds ?.

Even some crude bounds would be nice, or at least some recommendations on where I could find it.

Edit:

I know there should be bounds i.e. they exist
as the series is absolutely convergent for
$s > 1$.
However, how to  obtain these bounds ? is the question.
From an comment, there is a similar question, but the answer is based on a book which assumes $s = \sigma + {\rm i}t$ where
$\left\vert\,t\,\right\vert \geq 1$. In my question, I would like $t = 0$.


https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462212/bounds-for-hurwitz-zeta-functions

@ClaudeLeibovici This is only the case for $s=\sigma + it$ we have $|t| \geq 1$. This id from the Apostel book mentioned in the question. I would like to know if there are bounds for $t=0$.
